# CSS: my datetimepicking field is put behind my other inputfields

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm stuck on how to make my table which gets deployed through jquery in front of my input fields... I presume the problem is solvable with css but I can't seem to figure out specifically how to adjust it. (see image below)

I'm using eonasdan's bootstrap-datetimepicker (ref. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Any advice?

[image: Object set behind other fields]

Comment: You can control which elements go on top by using [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). Higher value means it shows up on top of elements with lower values.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio: Nice that was it alright! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you are missing `bootstrap-datetimepicker.css` (that includes CSS rules for proper display). See [Installing](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) section of the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by uom-pgregorio, I could easily solve this with the z-index. (I was trying with position: absolute before but that didn't do the trick)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the input datetimepicker, i am trying to see your code.. i think you are putting each div inside the another one.. put each one alone not inside each others.. if not so try position absolute for this input

```
  position:absolute;
```